# Where are the settings for "Find Files On Desktop"

Tags: 20.04

I just updated to Ubuntu 22.04.01 and I have dmenu installed. When I am on the desktop (no program running) and pull up dmenu and try to type in the program I'm wanting to run, the "Find Files on Desktop" feature comes up and it thinks I'm trying to type into it. How can I turn this off? Otherwise I need to be in another program to avoid waking this feature up to make dmenu run. Screenshot attached:
[Dmenu is open up top but typing wakes this feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Woysc.jpg)